# How can I implement Facebook comments in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-comments

I am trying to integrate Facebook comments into my iOS app.  I need to use Facebook in order to have one stream of comments from the regular site and the app to compile together.

Is there a way to do this other than creating a webview with Facebook's social plug in?

I want to be able to comment on specific video content and see the comments others have made on the existing site.

Answer (score 0):

Use Graph Api's from Facebook.
**https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_118464504835613/comments?access_token="user ur acces token"**

You can get the access token from  "**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/"**

You can also use **FQL**

{"query1":"SELECT post_id, actor_id, created_time, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND created_time<=now() LIMIT 5 ","query2":"SELECT post_id, id, fromid, time, text, user_likes, likes FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #query1) LIMIT 5 ","query3":"SELECT id, name, pic_square FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #query1) or id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query2)"}

USE **https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/** for HELP AND SUPPORT

Comment: This doesn't allow people to post from their facebook to the public comment feed within the app.